# return value of the function that is called in ajax process

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Am I able to access return value of the function that is called in ajax process(url given) inside success? For example, I am calling export() function in ex.php (url:ex.php) and that function return me the name of the exported file. I want to access this filename in ajax succes. (success:)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to echo the value from the php script. Like -

```
<?php echo export(); ?>
```

Now inside Ajax success(), you can just grab the ajax response to get the value.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ex.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert("Exported file name: " + data);
  }
})
```

Or even simpler version -

```
$.get("ex.php", function(data) {
  alert("Exported file name: " + data);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it's passed to the function you set as the success handler:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'myUrl.com',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data); //shows data returned from server
  }
})
```

Comment: inside 'data' what is always in my hand can include exported file content at the same time not only the return value?

Comment: data can be whatever is returned by the server. More specifically, it should be XML or JSON returned in the body of the HTTP response. jQuery will parse it into a javascript object. It can be literally anything you want. In PHP you could do something like "echo json_encode($result);" and that would show up as 'data'